# Php Regular Expression to Replace href=“URL” to onclick=myfunction(URL)

Tags: php, regex

With Php, I want to replace all links to a JavasSript function, for example:

From:
`<a href="URL">abc</a>`

to
`<a onclick="SomeFunction(URL);">abc</a>`

Comment: What happens to the `href` attribute? If you leave it out, some styles may not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use DOM operations like those provided by [PHP’s DOM](http://php.net/book.dom):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $elem) {
    if ($elem->hasAttribute('href')) {
        $elem->setAttribute('onclick', 'SomeFunction('.json_encode($elem->getAttribute('href')).')');
        $elem->removeAttribute('href');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but some web page lost some of its format. (Such as yahoo's main page, some element lost its '<')

Comment: Sorry, the problem I mentioned above is not related to this. Now it works pretty well.

Comment: One more question, what does json_encode do here? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function SomeFunction(url) {
  window.location.href = url;
 }
</script>
<?php

$html = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';

$html = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?)">/', '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="SomeFunction(\'$1\');">', $html);

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: How about for `<a class="someclass" href="URL">abc</a>`, there are something between 'a' and 'href' and I want to keep them?

Answer (score 0):

There is something to be said about parsing HTML without regex...

```
$str = 'Hello <a href="bob">bob</a>
<p><a href="hello">heya</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    $a->removeAttribute('href');
    $a->setAttribute('onclick', 'SomeFunction(\'' . $href . '\')');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

#### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html><body> 
<p>Hello <a onclick="SomeFunction('bob')">bob</a> 

</p> 
<p><a onclick="SomeFunction('hello')">heya</a></p> 
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the `href` just use

```
$elem->setAttribute('href', "")
```

or whatever the proper syntax is, I didn't test that.